# VBA: How to iterate through Outlook Inbox subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

I am attempting to pull all emails from an Outlook inbox subfolder and then pull the subject of each mail item.

I am defining the folders as such:

```
'Outlook folder- deifinitions
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("email@outlook.com")
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
    Dim InboxSubfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set InboxSubfolder = Inbox.Folders("To Be Logged")
```

I am getting

> Run-time Error '-2147221219 (8004011d)' The operation failed because
> of a registry or installation problem. Restart Outlook and try again.

Debug always highlights this line.

```
Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
```

This is on a fresh install of both Windows and Outlook.  I have restarted both Outlook and the computer.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to get the `Inbox` folder of the shared account?

Comment: Does it work in Outlook if you click "File | Open & Export | Other User's Folder" for the same address?

Answer (score 0):

If the Inbox folder comes from the account configured in Outlook you need to use the [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default `Inbox` folder for the user who is currently logged on.

```
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim InboxSubfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set InboxSubfolder = Inbox.Folders("To Be Logged")
```

Also you may find the required store in Outlook in case of multiple accounts configured using the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument.

This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.